Demand forecast in Supply Chain - Multivariate time series forcasting
I have a weekly time series data set as shown here :
date          product     vendor     stock   price
10-02-2023    product1     ZZZ         No     1344
10-09-2023    product1     ZZZ         No     9265
10-16-2023    product1     ZZZ         No     7854
.
.
.
05-06-2024    product1     ZZZ        No     784
10-02-2023    product2     XXX        Yes     564
10-09-2023    product2     XXX        ...     366
10-16-2023    product2     XXX        ...     646
.
.
.
05-06-2024    product2     XXX        Yes   4556
10-02-2023    product3     ZZZ              ...
10-09-2023    product3     ZZZ        ...
10-16-2023    product3     ZZZ        ...
.
.
.
05-06-2024    product3    ZZZ         Yes
.
.
So for each product I have a complete time series data that goes from 10-02-2023 to 05-06-2024 ( i have 1000 products)
I want to built a prediction model that , given a product 'producti', predicts the price for the date after 05-06-2024 .
The problem is that in my time series data a date is repeated 1000 times because I have 1000 products; however time series prediction models take as an input a data set where each date figures only onetime .
How shall I do to be able to train my model once at a time ? And which prediction model is suitable to my usecase  ?
thank you
